# Need help understanding a move script written for CMD involving multiple subdirectories into one directory

Tags: cmd, windows-10, command-prompt, move

I got a folder with a lot of images in it, and I'd like to move everything to the main folder so basically I would like to turn this:

L:\Pixiv\Tags\44324\Image1.jpg

L:\Pixiv\Tags\4564356\Image2.jpg

L:\Pixiv\Tags\325423\Image3.jpg

L:\Pixiv\Tags\16324\Image4.jpg

...into this

L:\Pixiv\Tags\Image1.jpg

L:\Pixiv\Tags\Image2.jpg

L:\Pixiv\Tags\Image3.jpg

L:\Pixiv\Tags\Image4.jpg

I did some looking, and I discovered a move function for CMD, and while most of it I can understand, some of it I can't, and frankly, I'm just that smart enough to know what happens when you start playing around with stuff you don't fully understand, so I don't do it. Point is your basic move function is basically something like "move c:\Whatever C:\Whocares," but as you can tell from below, this is a little more complicated.

```
for /r %d in (*) do move "%d" "d:\all snaps\"
```

/r I think goes through all the folders at the current target directory. So if I'm in L:\Pixiv\Artists and I type in this code for L:\Pixiv\Artists as a destination folder every file in Artists is going to be dumped into Tags. Is this correct?

%d I couldn't make sense out of, so I've no idea what it does. Also, for ease of use, I would like to put this in a batch script, because boy howdy, do I got a lot of folders that needs to be fixed. From what little I was able to read I should write the same as above, but change %d to %dd, correct? Also where at would I add a target directory, so I could just write a batch script, and be done with it? Also, apologies in advance for my lack of knowledge, usually I use Batchrun when it comes to automating stuff.

Comment: for testing/analyzing what it does, use `for /r %d in (*) do ECHO move "%d" "d:\all snaps\"`. The `ECHO` disables the `move` command and just prints it to the screen (not executing anything) This should help you recognize what `%d` (or `%%d` in batch files) does (if `for /?` didn't answer this question to you - I agree, it's a bit cryptic when you're new to it).

Comment: (oh, and congratulations for your `just smart enough... to not do it` attitude. That's a lot smarter than many new users here)

Comment: Currently looking through the readme from the command you gave me. While I could experiment with that, I find it easier to be told what %d does. Other than it being a variable I don't understand it's function. Also good news...managed to make a workable script for my purposes. Here it is just in case others need something similar.



pushd <directory>



for /r %%d in (*) do move "%%d" "<directory>"1